# Multiple textLabels in UITableViewCell in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to generate table cells which contains multiple textLabels but I can't even define textLabels.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {   
    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    cell.label1.text = "Hello" //error..value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'label1'
    cell.label2.text = "World" //error..

    return cell
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}
```

How to define textLabels in a UITableViewCell and how to put vertical space between them?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's because you never "defined" the labels. You have to add them as properties to a custom cell, instantiate that custom cell instead, and position them yourself, either via AutoLayout or with code.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Thanks for your answer. I defined it before  'var label1:UILabel' but I couldn't use it because it cannot be used like 'cell.label1.text'.. Any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot randomly declare labels in a cell. Watch this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adP2dG_C1XU) to create a custom `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 1):

`textLabel` is a valid property only if you have your table cell style set to one of the default types like "Basic". If you want to do something custom like create your own labels than you should specify "Custom" as the cell type.

[image: Setting the cell style to "Custom"]

You can then lay out your `UILabel`s and use constraints for AutoLayout just like you would with anything else in Interface Builder.

Now, because you are now using a custom cell, you will have to define a subclass of `UITableViewCell` for your cell so that you can access the labels.

Simply create a new Cocoa Touch Subclass of `UITableViewCell` such as this:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

}
```

Notice that those label properties are IBOutlets that were presumably created by control-dragging from the label in Interface Builder to our code, just like we would for any other UI outlet.

Actually, in order to be able to drag from IB to this class, we must specify that our prototype cell in IB is actually this class. To do that, simply specify the custom subclass in the inspector.

[image: Specifying our custom subclass.]

Note that this is the custom subclass of the cell, not the table view.

The only thing left to do is make sure our custom cell has an identifier in IB. In the field directly under "Style" in the attributes inspector, give your cell an identifier such as "cellID".

Now, to reference this from the controller, change your code to something like:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {   
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell

    cell.label1.text = "Hello"
    cell.label2.text = "World"

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}
```

Notice that we should not be creating cells with `UITableViewCell()` but instead `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. This allows our table view to automatically reuse cells efficiently. As long as we specified the correct identifier in the method parameters, we can be certain that the type will be `MyCell`, so we can go ahead and force-cast it.